# Combining Multiple SQL Views ON Year & Month

Tags: sql

I have a SQL Server database (2012 express) with many tables.
I have produced three different VIEWS based on different combinations of the underlying tables.
Each of these views consists of three columns, Year, Month & Total
The Total column in each of the 3 Views is of a different measure.
What I want to be able to do is to combine the three Totals into a single View

I have attempted this with the following script -

```
SELECT b.[Year], b.[Month], b.Fees AS [Billing],
       f.Estimate AS [Estimate],
       w.Fees AS [WIP]

FROM MonthlyBillingTotals AS b

FULL JOIN MonthlyFeeEstimates AS f
ON (b.[Year] = f.[Year] AND b.[Month] = f.[Month])

FULL JOIN MonthlyInstructionsWIP AS w
ON (b.[Year] = w.[Year] AND b.[Month] = w.[Month])

ORDER BY b.[Year], b.[Month]
```

Originally I tried INNER JOINS but of course unless the Year / Month combo existed in the first view (MonthlyBillingTotals) then it did not appear in the combined query.  I therefore tried FULL JOINS, but the problem here is that I get some NULLS in the Year and Month columns, when they do not exist in the first view (MonthlyBillingTotals).

If the data in the three Views is as follows -

[image]

Then what I want is -

[image]

And even better (if it is possible) -

[image]

with the missing months filled in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try building the full list of Months/Years from your tables using a `UNION` subquery, and then use that to drive your joins.. Something like this:

```
SELECT a.[Year], a.[Month], b.Fees AS [Billing],
       f.Estimate AS [Estimate],
       w.Fees AS [WIP]

FROM (SELECT a.[Year], a.[Month] FROM MonthlyBillingTotals AS a
      UNION 
      SELECT b.[Year], b.[Month] FROM MonthlyFeeEstimates AS b
      UNION 
      SELECT c.[Year], c.[Month] FROM MonthlyInstructionsWIP AS c) AS a 

LEFT OUTER JOIN MonthlyBillingTotals AS b
ON (a.[Year] = b.[Year] AND a.[Month] = b.[Month])

LEFT OUTER JOIN MonthlyFeeEstimates AS f
ON (a.[Year] = f.[Year] AND a.[Month] = f.[Month])

LEFT OUTER JOIN MonthlyInstructionsWIP AS w
ON (a.[Year] = w.[Year] AND a.[Month] = w.[Month])

ORDER BY a.[Year], a.[Month]
```

Comment: Generates the following error         Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
The multi-part identifier "a.Year" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
The multi-part identifier "a.Month" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
The multi-part identifier "a.Year" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
The multi-part identifier "a.Month" could not be bound.

Comment: Try it now.. had a bit of a typo.. the syntax is untested, but the general idea should give you what you need..

Comment: Oh, and depending on what database you're using, you should be able to replace the NULLS with '0' using coalesce or NVL..

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a small date table with year and month and left join the views with that, and use the `ISNULL(variable,0)` function to replace NULL with 0. Another option instead of a date table would be to use a common table expression to generate a date range to join with. In any case I suggest you look up the date table (or numbers table), it can be a really useful tool.

Edit: added an example on how a date table can be created (for reference):

```
declare @year_month table (y int, m int)

;with cte as (
  select cast('2000-01-01' as datetime) date_value
  union all
  select date_value + 1
  from cte   
  where date_value + 1 < '2010-12-31'
)

insert @year_month (y, m) 
select distinct year(date_value), month(date_value)
from cte
order by 1, 2
option (maxrecursion 0)

select * from @year_month
```

Comment: I considered this option but wouldn't that mean the Year / Month table would have to be manually updated every month?

Comment: @PJW You could easily build a date table for a long range in the future and when selecting from it use a where clause to filter the range you're interested in at the moment.

Comment: How would you suggest I initialize the values in the Year / Month table?  That could be a lot of manual input.

Comment: @PJW I updated my post to include an example on how to set up a simple date table.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely untested, but see if this solves your problems:

```
SELECT b.[Year], b.[Month], Coalesce(b.Fees, '0') AS [Billing],
       Coalesce(f.Estimate,'0') AS [Estimate],
       Coalesce(w.Fees,'0') AS [WIP]

FROM MonthlyBillingTotals AS b

LEFT JOIN MonthlyFeeEstimates AS f
ON (b.[Year] = f.[Year] AND b.[Month] = f.[Month])

LEFT JOIN MonthlyInstructionsWIP AS w
ON (b.[Year] = w.[Year] AND b.[Month] = w.[Month])

ORDER BY b.[Year], b.[Month]
```

The Coalesce function puts in a '0' value if nothing is found, and left joins should only join parts of MonthlyFeeEstimates and MonthlyInstructionsWIP when the year and month match.

Comment: This seems to omit some data when b.[Year] or b.[Month] are NULL